# What is the time complexity of entrySet in treeMap

Tags: java, algorithm

I am not sure if the time complexity of method entrySet() is O(n) or O(1).

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

map.entrySet();
```

Comment: Do you want to know the complexity of just calling the method `entrySet()` or of iterating over the entries of the entry set using `entrySet().iterator()` ?

Answer (score 1):

The point at which you call `entrySet()` there is no (significant) work to do beyond handing back a reference, so it's constant time. The map maintains sorted behavior as things are added to / removed from the `TreeMap`.

From the [Javadoc for TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> *This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations.*